# Why the name Talia ('the dew of God')

Tags: names, weather

The name Talia comes from 'the dew of God' according to the Wikipedia page. I think I am mostly bothered why someone would choose to name a person 'the dew of God.' Does the concept "God's dew" have significance in Judaism?

Answer (score 1):

Dew is connected in a number of texts to the resurrection of the dead. It probably stems from Isaiah 26:19:

> יִֽחְי֣וּ מֵתֶ֔יךָ נְבֵלָתִ֖י יְקוּמ֑וּן הָקִ֨יצוּ וְרַנְּנ֜וּ
>   שֹׁכְנֵ֣י עָפָ֗ר כִּ֣י טַ֤ל אוֹרֹת֙ טַלֶּ֔ךָ וָאָ֖רֶץ רְפָאִ֥ים
>   תַּפִּֽיל
>
> Oh, let Your dead revive! Let corpses arise! Awake and shout for joy,
>   You who dwell in the dust!— For Your dew is like the dew on fresh
>   growth; You make the land of the shades come to life.

And it's used by Rabban Gamliel in [Sanhedrin 90b](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.26.19?lang=bi&p2=Sanhedrin.90b.10&lang2=bi) as a prooftext for the resurrection, and in the [Zohar](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.118a.30/he/Torat_Emet_Zohar?lang=bi) and a couple other places too.

That's as to your second question - whether "God's dew" has significance in Judaism. I'm assuming the name Talia relates to this, but don't have a source.

Comment: See Yerushalmi Taanit 1:1 ומניין שאין המתים חיים אלא בטללים שנאמר (ישעיהו כו) יחיו מתיך נבלתי יקומון הקיצו ורננו שוכני עפר כי טל אורת טלך וארץ רפאים תפיל מהו וארץ רפאים תפיל

Answer (score 0):

Based on my Hebrew knowledge, טָלֶה (taleh) is the word for a ram, so טָלִיָה (talia) would mean an ewe. So perhaps the Wikipedia page listed one definition, but this makes more sense to me.